# Simple server-client socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to set up a simple server/client architecture using socket.io.

I have the following code in my `main.js`

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected')
})

http.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

I have the following code in my `client.js`

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
let socket = io(':3001')
```

I then run `node main.js` which prints "listening on *:3001", however when I run `node client.js` the expected "a user connected" is not printed. What am I missing in this simple architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you write it like this in your `client.js`:

`let socket = io('http://localhost:3001/')`